# Transformation between two equations for hyperbola: $y=\frac1x$ and $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

Back in school we were taught that the equation for hyperbola is:
$$y=\frac1x \tag1$$
The equation used in the university is different:
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1 \tag2$$

I can't understand how they are the same and how to get one from another.

What is the relation between these two forms?

Comment: Use the identity $4xy=(x^2+2xy+y^2)-(x^2-2xy+y^2)=(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2$.

Comment: One form is rotated 45 degrees from the other.

Comment: Short answer: If you play around with some numbers, you will see that
$$\tag{1}
(x+y)^2 - (x-y)^2 =4
$$
coinsides with $y=1/x$. Clearly, (1) is just a rotated and scaled hyperbola.

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Derivation

Comment: I am not agree with you that you have studied only the $xy=k$ and not $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$xy=1~~~~(1)$$ is rectangular hyperbola but
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1~~~~(2)$$ is more standard hyperbola.

Interestingly, (2) can also be written as
$$XY=1, X=\frac{x}{a}-\frac{y}{b}, Y=\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}~~~(3)$$
in the transformed co-ordinate system.

**EDIT:**
We can write $$\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix}=(ab)^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} b & -a \\ b & a \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$$
This transformation matrix can be belated to the rotataion matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin\theta     & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix}.$$ in a special case.

Comment: One of the $X$ or $Y$ should have a $+$ sign

Comment: Oh! yes thanks.

Comment: I still don't get it. I guess the key here is "in the transformed co-ordinate system", but the transformation seems quite arbitrary. Why did you define X and Y in exactly this way and what is the guarantee that the new curve in new coordinates has the same properties?

Comment: Please note that (1) and (2,3) are hyperbolas but with different properties.

Comment: Combined with the comment about [rotation of axes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Derivation) under the question your answer starts to make sense.

Comment: Could you please add an explanation to your answer that (1) is rotated and scaled (2) with the link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Derivation to make it more complete.

Answer (score 2):

Those are both hyperbolas, though the second equation is more "general" in the sense that it describes many different hyperbolas (precisely those with their foci on the x-axis).
Actually the equation $y = \frac{1}{x}$ describes the graphic of the "homographic function" which is an hyperbola such that it is tangent to both axises. This geometric transformation is necessary to make it an actual fuction.

To obtain the first from the second, first choose $a=b = \sqrt{2}$ in the second equation (in this way you obtain a rectangular hyperbola with perpendicular tangents, then rotate your hyperbola by -45° degrees, which is apply the following transformation:
\begin{align}
x &= \frac{\zeta +\eta}{\sqrt{2}}\\
y &= \frac{-\zeta +\eta}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{align}
Thus the second equation becomes
\begin{align}
\frac{2\zeta\eta}{2} = 1
\end{align}
Solving for $\eta$ you obtain
\begin{align}
\eta = \frac{1}{\zeta}
\end{align}
Now changing name of your variables you get the first equation.
Can you see why now this is a function?